# How to do continous merge in Git

Tags: git, svn, merge

In svn I can merge from branch to trunk by specifying the revision number like this

```
trunk>svn merge -r r1:r2 <branch>
```

However, in git, it seems like the merge is always a reintegration merge which converge the branch to trunk. So after that if do merge again, the change will not based on the point when previous merge occurred.

```
   B--C----E----F-----G     --> origin/dev
  /    \               \
 /      \               \
A--------D---------------H------- origin/master
```

So, when first merge from dev to master at D, it is correct for sure. But second time when merge from G back to H, the merge's compare point is based on C not D because the merge at D at first is a reintegration merge and I got some conflicts!

So, how to continuous merge in Git?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There's no need to merge commits B and C back to master in the second merge, they've already been applied to master. The second merge only needs to merge E, F and G. There's always the possibility of merge conflicts, it depends on what the changes to the two branches have been.

Comment: How to merge e,f,g, what command should I use?

Comment: You checkout master, ensure it is up to date with origin/master and then just do `git merge origin/dev`. Then, if you're happy with the merge you just push it to origin with `git push origin master`.

Comment: Why the 2nd time may contain conflicts? It doesn't make sense since no change has been committed to master after the first merge. What you did is exactly what I did, however, it results in conflicts. This is why I guess git doesn't do continuous merge.

Comment: Even if there are no non-merge commits to `origin/master` after D then there my still be conflicts merging in `origin/dev` as commits E-G may touch files which are different between C and D because they have been changed between A and D. These changes won't be on the `origin/dev` branch, only the `origin/master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

The “compare point” in this case is not A, it’s actually C, because that is where your branches diverged. And suddenly it all makes sense.

Comment: But… that is already the answer. From C you have two diverging branches, A does not matter anymore, so H is just a normal merge.

Comment: Then how to do the continuous merge if I want to keep the dev branch for development and merge to trunk for QA release? I need to be able to continuously merge from dev without deleting dev and recreating dev every time.

Comment: @sza: You can do that. What makes you think that you can't?

Comment: @sza, just merge it! You can without any problem merge `dev` into `master` whenever you see fit! Git knows what has already been merged, you don’t have to specify which commits should be merged as you had to do with Subversion.

Comment: @bombe It results in conflicts(no new conflicts have been pushed to master after D) This is why I guess git doesn't do continuous merge.

Comment: Then you must have done something different. A situation like the one you described would not result in a merge conflict. Git can do continuous merging, has been able to do it form the very beginning, and it in fact encourages it because knows exactly what to merge and when.